# Каким образом следует переводить термин email?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Переводить email как "сообщения электронной почты", имхо, совсем неудачная затея. Предлагаю упростить до:

- email - почта
- email message - сообщение по почте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

`email` - почта

это ок.

`email message` - <s>сообщение</s> письмо

Добавлять "по почте" нет смысла.